# Qiskit unitary representation seems shifted

Tags: qiskit

I have implemented a simple CNOT gate using `qiskit`

I was expecting a the result the matrix as in the following image (extracted from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate)):

[image: CNOT WIKI]

```
from qiskit import *
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
simulator = Aer.get_backend("unitary_simulator")
result = execute(circuit, backend=simulator).result()
unitary = result.get_unitary()
print(circuit.draw())
print(unitary)
```

The results in the print are:

[image: Results]

If you pay attention, it seems the order of the qbits is reversed. I would like to know why this happens and if it's normal because it seems confusing at first glance.

To be really clear: The matrix in the first image and the second (the result) should be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first matrix is generally seen in books, as you consider computational basis in the order $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$, $|2\rangle$, $|3\rangle$ or in bitstrings $|00\rangle$, $|01\rangle$, $|10\rangle$, $|11\rangle$. So basically, you think as $| q_0, q_1\rangle$. This is called little-endian convention.

But in Qiskit, they use the inverse, aka big-endian convention. And then you have to think that it is actually $| q_1, q_0\rangle$. And what you do is that you define $q_0$ as the control. So when $| q_1 = 1, q_0 = 0\rangle$ that is 1 in big-endian, $CNOT |10\rangle = | 10\rangle$, hence 3. Which explains your second row.
And when $| q_1 = 1, q_0 = 1\rangle$ that is 3 in big-endian, $CNOT |11\rangle = | 01\rangle$, hence 1 and explaining why you get the last row.

You can find the [explanation about the CNOT in Qiskit here](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-gates/multiple-qubits-entangled-states.html).

Answer (score 3):

In Qiskit, the bits are reversed order from most textbook definitions. That is to say the zeroth qubit is the farthest to the right in a bitstring or tensor product.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification. Do you know if it's for any particular reason? It seemed confusing at first. Also, any simple numpy function to reverse the order?

Comment: It was just a design decision to be more inline with cs notation.